# Rendering a Web Component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component, lit-element

In [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-web-component-stripping-dom-sanitizer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) the `HelloComponent` includes a web component `fs-image` within the rendered markup.  This is the component:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="safeHTML"></div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  constructor(private dm: DomSanitizer) {
    this.safeHTML = this.dm.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.html);
  }
  @Input() name: string;
  safeHTML: SafeHtml;

  html: string = `
  <h1> Web Component Test</h1>
  <fs-image url="https://fireflysemantics.github.io/i/developer/instant-html-vscode.png"></fs-image>
  `;
}
```

The `html` property containing the web component is passed through `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml` such that Angular does not strip the custom element.

So when the component renders it does include the custom element, however it is not rendering.  It's supposed to render like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fs-image-demo

The web component is included via CDN in the header.  The CDN declaration looks like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fireflysemantics/fs-image"></script>
</head>
```

Any ideas on why it's not rendering?

Answer (score 0):

OK - Got it.  In this case the `fs-image` uses `100%` for the width and height, so I had to put it in a container that specifies height.